# How to build a simple rosjava package successfully?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [rosjava_tutorial_pubsub](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core/Tutorials/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub) and [rosjavaのプロジェクト作成＆Talker作成](http://ros-robot.blogspot.tw/2012/07/rosjavatalker.html).

I run:

```
  roscreate-pkg sam_rosjava_basic
  cd sam_rosjava_basic/
```

My build.gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'java'
  
  // The Maven plugin is only required if your package is used as a library.
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  
  // The Application plugin and mainClassName attribute are only required if
  // your package is used as a binary.
  apply plugin: 'application'
  mainClassName = 'org.ros.RosRun'
  
  sourceCompatibility = 1.6
  targetCompatibility = 1.6
  
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public'
    }
  }
  
  version = '0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  group = 'ros.my_stack'
  
  dependencies {
    compile 'ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
```

And I run:

```
  mkdir -p src/main/java
```

My src/main/java/talker.java:

```
   package org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub;
  
  import org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop;
  import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
  import org.ros.node.AbstractNodeMain;
  import org.ros.node.ConnectedNode;
  import org.ros.node.NodeMain;
  import org.ros.node.topic.Publisher;
  
  /**
   * A simple {@link Publisher} {@link NodeMain}.
   * 
   * @author damonkohler@google.com (Damon Kohler)
   */
  public class Talker extends AbstractNodeMain {
  
    @Override
    public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
      return new GraphName("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker");
    }
  
    @Override
    public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
      final Publisher<std_msgs.String> publisher =
          connectedNode.newPublisher("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
      // This CancellableLoop will be canceled automatically when the node shuts
      // down.
      connectedNode.executeCancellableLoop(new CancellableLoop() {
        private int sequenceNumber;
  
        @Override
        protected void setup() {
          sequenceNumber = 0;
        }
  
        @Override
        protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {
          std_msgs.String str = publisher.newMessage();
          str.setData("Hello world! " + sequenceNumber);
          publisher.publish(str);
          sequenceNumber++;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Then I run:

```
  sam@/home/sam$ `rosstack find rosjava_core`/gradlew installApp
  bash: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/gradlew: No such file or directory      
  sam@/home/sam$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

===================================================

I try to use rosws to init my workspace,download rosjava,and rosmake successfully!

I run:

```
  cd ~/code/ros
  rosws init
  echo 'source ~/code/ros/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
  rosws merge /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall
  rosws merge http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall
  rosws update
  cd rosjava_core/
  rosmake
```

But when I try:

```
   sam@/home/sam/code/ros/java/sam_rosjava_basic$ `rosstack find rosjava_core`/gradlew installApp
  Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip
  .................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
  Unzipping /home/sam/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip to /home/sam/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks
  Set executable permissions for: /home/sam/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9/bin/gradle
  :compileJava
  
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  
  * What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
  > Could not find group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
    Required by:
        ros.my_stack:sam_rosjava_basic:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  
  BUILD FAILED
  
  Total time: 2 mins 29.874 secs
  
  sam@/home/sam/code/ros/java/sam_rosjava_basic$
```

I try again with sudo:

```
   sam@/home/sam/code/ros/java/sam_rosjava_basic$ sudo `rosstack find rosjava_core`/gradlew installApp
  [sudo] password for sam: 
  Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip
  .................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
  Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks
  Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9/bin/gradle
  :compileJava
  
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  
  * What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
  > Could not find group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
    Required by:
        ros.my_stack:sam_rosjava_basic:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  
  BUILD FAILED
  
  Total time: 1 mins 49.333 secs
  
  sam@/home/sam/code/ros/java/sam_rosjava_basic$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41455/how-to-build-a-simple-rosjava-package-successfully?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-17**:
Please ask only one question at a time, and do not change the question. You need to run gradlew install in rosjava_core first, not rosmake. Never use sudo, unless a tutorial tells you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to follow the directions exactly as they are described in the documentation. rosmake has no effect in rosjava_core. Your package is failing to build because you have not executed the install task for rosjava_core.

Follow the directions, make sure the tutorials build as described, and then try your project again.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-02**:
What I know is trying to follow the doc. I can't understand what you told to me. I have already run 'rosws merge [http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall'](http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall%27). What can I do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [caca](https://answers.ros.org/users/5143/caca/) on 2013-06-20**:
Create a package in ~/<your_ws>/rosjava_core/ and follow this link http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-java-package

you must create package rosjava_core and if everything is okey, you run ../gradlew installApp.